# Formating excel spread sheet export from multiple datagridviews vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, export

I am currently working in microsoft visual studio 2013 with an sql back end. I am loading multiple DGVs' and then trying to export them to an excel spread sheet. However, I am not sure how to format this data. When I try and export multiple DGVs' they write over top of each other in the top left hand corner of the excel file. Does anyone know how to format and select where you want the DGVs' to load on the excel spreadsheet. I don't want them all to be on different sheets either. Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub BtnExcelExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExcelExport.Click

    Try

        Dim xlapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlworkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlworksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misvalue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim J As Integer

        xlapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue)
        xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

        For I = 0 To DGVJobs.RowCount - 1
            For J = 0 To DGVJobs.ColumnCount - 1
                For K As Integer = 1 To DGVJobs.Columns.Count
                    xlworksheet.Cells(1, K) = DGVJobs.Columns(K - 1).HeaderText
                    xlworksheet.Cells(I + 2, J + 1) = DGVJobs(J, I).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next

        'Here is my second DGV upload out of a few, this one will write over top of the other
        For I = 0 To DGVAssociates.RowCount - 1
            For J = 0 To DGVAssociates.ColumnCount - 1
                For K As Integer = 1 To DGVAssociates.Columns.Count
                    xlworksheet.Cells(1, K) = DGVAssociates.Columns(K - 1).HeaderText
                    xlworksheet.Cells(I + 2, J + 1) = DGVAssociates(J, I).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next

        xlworksheet.SaveAs("C:\example.xlsx")
        xlworkbook.Close()
        xlapp.Quit()

        releaseobject(xlapp)
        releaseobject(xlworkbook)
        releaseobject(xlworksheet)


        MsgBox("You can find the file C:\example.xlsx")
        Dim res As MsgBoxResult
        res = MsgBox("Saving completed, would you like to open the file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
            Process.Start("C:\example.xlsx")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub releaseobject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The second for loop is where I am having the over-write problem. If anyone has a link that can send me to a good website please post it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping twice throuhg the columns? The most inner loop is unnecesary.

Now, the variables you're using to specify the column to write to in excel go from 0 to `ColumnCount` in both groups of `For`s. That's why they're overwriting each other.

Try this:

```
For I = 0 To DGVJobs.RowCount - 1
    For J = 0 To DGVJobs.ColumnCount - 1
        xlworksheet.Cells(1, J + 1) = DGVJobs.Columns(J).HeaderText
        xlworksheet.Cells(I + 2, J + 1) = DGVJobs(J, I).Value.ToString()
    Next
Next

For I = 0 To DGVAssociates.RowCount - 1
    For J = 0 To DGVAssociates.ColumnCount - 1
        xlworksheet.Cells(1, J + 1 + DGVJobs.ColumnCount) = DGVAssociates.Columns(K - 1).HeaderText
        xlworksheet.Cells(I + 2, J + 1 + DGVJobs.ColumnCount) = DGVAssociates(J, I).Value.ToString()
    Next
Next
```

(BTW and off-topic; a faster way to export data to excel is to first create an array with all the data and then asign it to the corresponding `Range` in the worksheet)

Comment: The inner-most loop takes care of the K variable. I out your code into my vb.net and it was missing that variable. If the array is a better way to do this could you shoot me some example code of how to drop in multiple data grid views into an array.

Comment: What I meant is that you don't really need `k`, at least not for the code you posted. Now, will both grids always have the same number of rows?

Comment: no, I have a total of 6 datagridviews. 4 of them will always have one row and the other 2 will vary,

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code, Then You Will Surely Text Me a Message of Thanks :)

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.IO

 Private Sub ExportToExcel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExportToExcel.Click

    Try
        Dim xlapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlworkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlworksheet, xlworksheet1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misvalue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim J As Integer

        xlapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue)
        xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


        For I = 0 To DataGridView_Report.RowCount - 1
            For J = 0 To DataGridView_Report.ColumnCount - 1
                For K As Integer = 1 To DataGridView_Report.Columns.Count
                    xlworksheet.Cells(1, K) = DataGridView_Report.Columns(K - 1).HeaderText
                    xlworksheet.Cells(I + 2, J + 1) = DataGridView_Report(J, I).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next

        xlworksheet1 = CType(xlworkbook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)

        For I = 0 To DataGridView_Calculation.RowCount - 1
            For J = 0 To DataGridView_Calculation.ColumnCount - 1
                For K As Integer = 1 To DataGridView_Calculation.Columns.Count
                    xlworksheet1.Cells(1, K) = DataGridView_Calculation.Columns(K - 1).HeaderText
                    xlworksheet1.Cells(I + 2, J + 1) = DataGridView_Calculation(J, I).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next

        xlworksheet.Columns.AutoFit()
        xlworksheet1.Columns.AutoFit()

        Dim xlRange, xlRange1 As Excel.Range
        xlRange = xlworksheet.Range("A1", "N1")
        xlRange1 = xlworksheet1.Range("A1", "L1")
        xlRange.Columns.Font.Bold = True
        xlRange1.Columns.Font.Bold = True

        xlworksheet.Name = "My Sheet1"
        xlworksheet1.Name = "My Sheet2"

        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls|Excel Workbook 2011|*.xlsx"
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Excel File"
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Export " & Now.ToShortDateString & ".xlsx"
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:/"
        If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then

            Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = CType(saveFileDialog1.OpenFile(), System.IO.FileStream)
            fs.Close()
        End If


        Dim strFileName As String = saveFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim blnFileOpen As Boolean = False


        Try
            Dim fileTemp As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(strFileName)
            fileTemp.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            blnFileOpen = False
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
        End If

        xlworkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
        xlapp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
        xlapp.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
errorhandler:
            MsgBox(Err.Description)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub releaseobject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```